# I need to change the style of a class

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WP where i want to change an element style.

This is what i have in console when i inspect with firebug:

```
<div class="height-fixed" style="/* height: 155px; */"></div>
```

And then on the right in Styles i have

```
element.style {
height: 155px;
}
```

I need this value to be 0
How can i change the element.style in the custom CSS editor?

I already tryed with:

```
.height-fixed[style]{height:0px; !important;}
```

and nothing happens

Comment: What exactly is the motive in setting height to 0? If there is a content inside the div, even if you set the height to 0, the content would be visible in DOM. And it looks like the inline style is commented.

Comment: this is my page https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/home-2/ and with that modification I want to get rid of the space betwwen the menu and the image

Comment: The reason causes the space between the menu and the image is this css:
#main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

Change this to #main {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

Comment: Thank you , works perfect!!!!